# Terraform get element name from the list

Tags: terraform

Let's say I have a list of variables similar to the following:

```
"first" = {
    action = "trigger"
    env    = "prod"
}
```

I know that I can get the values of `action` and `env` variables in the foreach loop using `${each.value["action"]}` and `${each.value["env"]}`.
How would I go around getting the "**first**" field (name of the element in a list)?

I would appreciate any help on this!

Answer (score 2):

Please understand first how `for_each` works and what `each` object [1] is. The `for_each` meta-argument can work with sets or maps. You are using maps. A map is represented by keys and values. Since you already know how to use values, the way to get a key in a map is with `each.key`. If your map has more than one key, you can get all of the keys with the built-in `keys` function [2].

---

[1] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each

[2] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/keys